# PL/SQL code to get redirected URL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've been asked to write PL/SQL code to get the URL of the directed page.

One URL may be automatically redirected to other URL.

For example the link `http://www.arabseed.com` maybe redirected to `http://www.arabseed.com/ar/home.html`.

So my PL/SQL block should accept first URL and return second one. I have looked @ htp pkg in Oracle API and it did not help me a lot.

Comment: Do you want to find the redirects on your own site or from anywhere in the web?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

from the info you gave us I'm only able to come up with this:

```
function get_redirected_url (url varchar2) return varchar2 is
begin
  case url
    when 'http://www.arabseed.com' then return 'http://www.arabseed.com/ar/home.html';
    when /* other URLs go here */
    else return '';
  end;
end;
```

However, I'm pretty sure that's not what you've been asked for. You'll have to refine your question.

Perhaps it's all your managers fault, because in fact the webserver would handle the default redirects.

Comment: Its pretty obvious he wants to get the redirects from the http server

Comment: but i want to make it dynamic . means to accept any url and return the directed one

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure your boss didn't mean for other people to do your work for you.
If you'd look at the [UTL_HTTP documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10577/u_http.htm#i1027499) you will find examples that do 70% of the work for you.

In any case, here what you are looking for (for just one redirect, I trust you'll be able to modify it to a series of redirects):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 40000

DECLARE
  req   UTL_HTTP.REQ;
  resp  UTL_HTTP.RESP;
  name  VARCHAR2(256);
  value VARCHAR2(1024);
BEGIN
  req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST('http://www.arabseed.com');
  UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(req, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
  UTL_HTTP.SET_FOLLOW_REDIRECT(req, 0);
  resp := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(req);
  IF(resp.STATUS_CODE in (UTL_HTTP.HTTP_MOVED_PERMANENTLY,UTL_HTTP.HTTP_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT, UTL_HTTP.HTTP_FOUND))
  THEN
    FOR i IN 1..UTL_HTTP.GET_HEADER_COUNT(resp) LOOP
       UTL_HTTP.GET_HEADER(resp, i, name, value);
       if(name ='Location')
       THEN
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Redirecting to:' || value);
       END IF;
     END LOOP;
   END IF;  
  UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(resp);
END;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel Haviv for your help . realy I have two issues , first of them is Error Message says - ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1029 ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist ORA-06512: at line 10 . line 10 is req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST('http://www.oracle.com'); . i'm using oracle10g db

Comment: This error is because the machine you're running your db on cant resolve dns addresses (just a matter of configuration)