# Accessing HTTP Header Info

Tags: oracle, plsql, get, http-headers, oracle11g

I'm using Oracle 11g, together with F5 BIG-IP network and Glassfish app server and was wondering how, using pl/sql, access HTTP Header GET information, which should also include LDAP info from the F5?

Comment: this might point you to the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455696/pl-sql-code-to-get-redirected-url/8456254#8456254

Answer (score 3):

Specifically, maybe this part will help:

--

**Retrieving HTTP Response Headers**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 40000

DECLARE
  req   UTL_HTTP.REQ;
  resp  UTL_HTTP.RESP;
  name  VARCHAR2(256);
  value VARCHAR2(1024);
BEGIN
  UTL_HTTP.SET_PROXY('proxy.my-company.com', 'corp.my-company.com');
  req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST('http://www-hr.corp.my-company.com');
  UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(req, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
  resp := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(req);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HTTP response status code: ' || resp.status_code);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HTTP response reason phrase: ' || resp.reason_phrase);
  FOR i IN 1..UTL_HTTP.GET_HEADER_COUNT(resp) LOOP
    UTL_HTTP.GET_HEADER(resp, i, name, value);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(name || ': ' || value);
  END LOOP;
  UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(resp);
END;
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked at the [UTL_HTTP supplied package documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_http.htm)? Not sure it has what you're looking for, but I'd start there.